# characters issue when exporting as a csv file in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, export-to-csv, special-characters

I have a pl/sql block that exporting some data as a csv file. unfortunately, when I open this file with excel I am having characters issue. When I open the file in notepad, it seems okay but not working in excel. any idea? thanks.

data in the table

[image: 1]

data in the excel

[image: 2]

data in notepad

[image: 3]

try to set NLS_LANGUAGE but not working

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: How do you export the file? What is your code?

Comment: Parameter `NLS_LANGUAGE` is used for Oracle error messages and Date formats, it does not effect any characters settings.

Comment: If you can open the file in notepad withoud any problem (as you stated) then you should check your Windows (region) setting or Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue.
Open your file in binary mode, using

```
t_fh := utl_file.fopen( p_dir, p_filename, 'wb' );
```

And use this to write to it

```
utl_file.put_raw( t_fh, utl_i18n.string_to_raw( 'èéê', 'WE8MSWIN1252' ) );

UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW(v_file_handle, v_newline);

v_newline     RAW(2)     := hextoraw('0A');
```

So I don’t have any special characters issue anymore